# Unreal Engine 4.18 - Knife (Weapon) collides with character capsule collision

Tags: collision-detection, movement, unreal-4, socket

I have a character and he has a knife in his hand. When Run / Walk action happens hands move and so does knife, its collision collides with character's capsule collision and causes issue in movement.

More info: 
Component Hierarchy looks like

[image: Component Hierarchy]

[image: Movement issue]
[image: Idle state]

Comment: There was a [similar question asked recently in the context of Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/151667/issue-giving-object-players-hand-position/151676), which might give you some leads toward an Unreal solution.

Comment: Yes, that gave me the idea and the issue is resolved.

Comment: can some one upvote @DMGregory s comment for me?

Comment: Haha, no worries, I have more votes than I really need. I'm glad you were able to find a solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

Following is the answer for blueprints

**Ignore Knife with reference to Capsule Component**

1. In your **character blueprint** > **event graph** draw a new connection from **Event BeginPlay** node, select **Ignore Actor when Moving** from list
2. It has two pins **Target** and **Actor**, Set **Target** to **Capsule Component** reference
3. For **Actor** you kneed to connect the Knife, but Knife is not exactly a true actor, it is a child actor component (A component that spawns an actor when registered, and destroys when unregistered, so do the following)

[image: Get Knife]

4. Don't forget to check **should ignore** third key

[image: Complete blueprint]

that's it, now your **Knife** will be ignored by your **Capsule Component**

thanks to [@DMGregory](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/39518) for the lead